# What is the integral of $\frac{e^z}{z^2-9}$ on the circle $|z|=2$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

What is the integral of $$\frac{e^z}{z^2-9}$$ on the circle $|z|=2$. 
The conditions of Cauchy formula does not fulfill. 
That is why I triet using: $$z=f(t)=0+2e^{it}$$ while $t$ is between $0$ and $2\pi$ and $$f'(t)=2ie^{it}$$ and got a real integral that I did not know how to make.

Comment: I think this is NBHM question?

Comment: What do you mean by NBHM?

Comment: National Board of Higher Mathematics

Comment: If there are no poles inside the contour, what does that mean for the function?

Comment: Analytic function in the domain $|z|<2$

Comment: Why do you say that Cauchy's Theorem is not applicable?

Comment: And what is the closed loop integral of an analytic function?

Comment: Because nor 3 or -3  are in the domain $|z|<2$

Comment: Closed loop integral of analytic function is zero.

Comment: But the loop here is not in the domain $|z|<2$.. Can I take this domain $|z|<3$ ?

Comment: What is the sum of the residues of the poles inside the path of integration?

Comment: Is Zero the answer to your question ,Eric Towers?